# Expecting error message for wrong MySQL command

Tags: mysql, linux

I have this command in linux

```
mysql -u xyz -p -e "show databases"
```

Where, the user "**xyz**" doesn't exist. When it asks for password

1. if i don't give any password it doesn't give error message or a non-zero value when i run `echo $?` command.
2. if i give a password it gives error message

Any reason why? And any suggestions what I have to do to get an error message for this command?

Comment: `mysql -e "show databases"` works too so my guess is that it never authenticates the user in this case. It does however limit the databases shown to those without user limits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there is no other way but to run-

```
mysql -u xyz -p -e "use mysql"
```

as mysql database doesn't exist for non existing users.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
mysql -u xyz -pYourPassword -e "show databases"
```

Or:

```
mysql -u xyz --password=YourPassword -e "show databases"
```

Comment: that works as expected. but if i don't give any password then i don't get error message.Is there a way where i can fix that?